# Getting root with setuid and the s flag

Tags: linux, c, permissions

Ok, so I'm trying to wrap my head around what the s flag does in linux.

I've got the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
  gid_t gid;
  uid_t uid;
  gid = getegid();
  uid = geteuid();

  printf("gid %d\n",gid);
  printf("uid %d\n",uid);

  setresgid(gid, gid, gid);
  setresuid(uid, uid, uid);

  system("id");
}
```

and the s flag is set for user.

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 7358 2017-08-24 17:45 a.out
```

so to my understanding, since the s flag is set, the effective gid, and uid should be the user.

However when I run this file as another user I get the following.

```
nebula@nebula:/tmp$ ./a.out 
gid 1000
uid 1000
uid=1000(nebula) gid=1000(nebula) groups=1000(nebula),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),109(sambashare),110(admin)
```

I believe that this shows that the effective uid and gid were not set the way I would have thought.

Any help?? Thanks!

Comment: Since `geteuid()` does not return correct root value, try `setreuid(-1, 0)`. (Or use getresuid() to access the save uid instead of the effective one.)

Answer (score 1):

Filesystems can be mounted with setuid disabled. This is normally done on removable devices (because the administrator has no control over what the removable device contains) and on network filesystems (unless the filesystem is mounted from a trusted server). It is good practice to do it for all filesystems that aren't supposed to allow privilege escalation, such as a filesystem for temporary files.

Check the mount point where your setuid executable is located:

```
df /tmp
```

Chances are that on your machine, `/tmp` is a separate filesystem — you'll see `/tmp` in the “Mounted on” column. Check the mount options for `/tmp`; on Linux you can look them up in `/proc/mounts`:

```
grep /tmp /proc/mounts
```

If you see `nosuid` as one of the options in the fourth column, the filesystem is mounted with setuid and setgid disabled: `ls` still lists the bits and `chmod` still changes them, but they have no effect.

Do your experiments on another filesystem. `/var/tmp` is usually mounted on the same filesystem as `/` and that one needs setuid enabled for programs like `(/usr)/bin/su` and `(/usr)/bin/sudo`.

The setuid/setgid bits can also be disabled via a security framework such as SELinux. See [this thread on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/324002/bin-su-permission-denied-after-selinux-is-enabled-not-resolved-by-manual-crea) for how to investigate this.

Answer (score 0):

1. There seems to be a minor bug in your program.

You have the s bit set only for owner, not group, but you're using the gid when for all params in setresuid & setresgid (lines 17 & 18). 
[edit:] Because of this, the gid will belong to the user who runs the program, not the owner of a.out.

If you change the params on those lines to uid, you should get the expected result. Subject to #2 below.

2. The output for the geteuid seems anomalous. It should be 0. I would investigate it if I were you. I'm unable to replicate it though.

If you're only concerned about why setresuid and setresgid aren't working properly, set them to 0 (or any valid uid/gid numbers) and see what happens.

BTW, you should check for their return values.